# When is a Jersey Rest service actually started/closed?

Tags: java, ajax, rest, tomcat, jersey

So I have a Jersey REST service on a Tomcat server that takes client requests, processes them with an Entity Manager to get data from a database, then sends back a response to the client. So my question is, when is my REST class (containing the URL paths and such) created/destroyed? Is it created fresh with every new AJAX request or does it stay running and open on the server indefinitely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey basically runs as a single servlet that handles all of the requests. When a request is received, the URI+media types is matched (by the servlet implementation) against all the paths you have defined in your various Jersey-annotated classes. If a match is found, Jersey instantiates the relevant class and invokes the proper method and does all the appropriate magic based on annotations and return types.

The one Jersey servlet gets started once. Your Jersey-annotated class gets a new instance for each request that it handles. I usually have a bunch of @Context-annotated parameters for my constructor, so that I have all the relevant context for the request (request, URI, headers, security context, etc.) available to my API implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! All I needed to know.